# What is the best way to output new lines to the shell from php?

Tags: php, shell, comments

I like to output a lot of detail to the shell when my PHP scripts are running.

I have a lot of lines like this:

```
echo "\n\n" . __method__ . " - PDF file does not exist.";
```

It bugs the hell out of me that there are so many `\n`s everywhere in my code.  Is there a better way to do this?  Is there something simple that I'm missing, perhaps?

What are some preferred ways to do this in some major php libraries?

Comment: You could write yourself some kind of `writeln()` function to suppress these many new-lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No standard way in PHP.

But you could write a function to do that....

```
function shellprint($string)
{
    echo($string . "\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'v tested this and other ways of doing it, but none worked.

The **rusty** way it works is having something like

```
        if ($something==true)
        {
             echo 'Hello
This is a new line.
and this another new line';
        }
```

I wanna have a nice indent style on my code, so I created a small function to solve it.

```
function shecho($text) {
    $text = str_replace('\n', '
', $text);
    echo $text; 
}
```

This way I will only have to write

```
shecho ('Hello\nThis is a new line.\nand this another new line');
```

Easy stuff.
Hope it helps anyone!